# Как получить из БД нужное значение и поставить его в TextView?

Tags: java, android

Имеются: разметка

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D6D8F2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_below="@id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="СФЕРА ТРУДА"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Человек"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Информация"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Финансы"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Техника" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Искусство"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Животные"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Растения"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Продукты питания"
                />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Изделия"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Природные ресурсы"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ВИД ТРУДА"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/rg1"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Управление"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Обслуживание"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Образование"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Оздоровление"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Творчество"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Производство"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Конструирование"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Исследование питания"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Защита"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Контроль"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/bt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rg2"
            android:text="РЕЗУЛЬТАТ"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bt2"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Активность 1:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db"; // название бд
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "matrix"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPHERE = "sphere";
    public static final String COLUMN_KIND = "kind";
    public static final String COLUMN_ENTITY = "entity";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_SPHERE
                + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_KIND + " INTEGER, " + COLUMN_ENTITY + " TEXT );");
        // добавление начальных данных
        String string = "Менеджер по персоналу:Администратор.Маркетолог:Диспетчер:Статистик.Экономист:Аудитор:Аналитик.Технолог:Авиадиспетчер:Инженер.Режиссер:Продюсер:Дирижер.Кинолог:Зоотехник:Генный инженер.Агроном:Фермер:Селекционер.Товаровед:Менеджер по продажам.Менеджер по продажам:Логистик:Товаровед.Энергетик:Инженер по кадастру.Продавец:Парикмахер:Официант.Переводчик:Экскурсовод:Библиотекарь.Бухгалтер:Кассир:Инкассатор.Водитель:Слесарь:Теле-радио мастер.Гример:Костюмер:Парикмахер.Животновод:Птицевод:Скотовод.Овощевод:Полевод:Садовод.Экспедитор:Упаковщик:Продавец.Продавец:Упаковщик:Экспедитор.Егерь:Лесник:Мелиоратор.Учитель:Воспитатель:Социальный педагог.Преподаватель:Ведущий теле-радио программ.Консультант:Преподаватель экономики.Мастер производственного обучения.Хореограф:Преподаватель музыки, живописи.Дрессировщик:Кинолог:Жокей.Преподаватель биологии:Эколог.Мастер производственного обучения.Мастер производственного обучения.Преподаватель:Эколог.Врач:Медсестра:Тренер.Рентгенолог:Врач (компьютерная диагностика).Антикризисный управляющий:Страховой агент.Мастер автосервиса:Физиотерапевт. Пластический хирург:Косметолог:Реставратор.Ветеринар:Лаборант питомника:Зоопсихолог.Фитотерапевт:Гомеопат:Травник.Диетолог:Косметолог:Санитарный инспектор.Фармацевт:Ортопед:Протезист.Бальнеолог:Эпидемиолог:Лаборант.Режиссер:Артист:Музыкант.Программист:Редактор:Web-дизайнер.Менеджер по проектам:Продюсер.Коструктор:Дизайнер:Художник.Художник:Писатель:Композитор.Дрессировщик:Служитель цирка.Фитодизайнер:Озеленитель:Флорист.Кондитер:Повар:Кулинар.Резчик по дереву:Витражист:Скульптор.Архитектор:Цветовод:Декоратор.Мастер производственного обучения.Корректор:Журналист:Полиграфист.Экономист:Бухгалтер:Кассир.Станочник:Аппаратчик:Машинист.Ювелир:График:Керамист.Животновод:Птицевод:Рыбовод.Овощевод:Цветовод:Садовод.Технолог:Калькулятор:Повар.Швея:Кузнец:Столяр.Шахтер:Нефтяник:Техник.Стилист:Пластический хирург.Картограф:Программист:Web-мастер.Плановик:Менеджер по проектам.Инженер-конструктор:Телемастер.Архитектор:Дизайнер:Режиссер.Генный инженер:Виварщик:Селекционер.Селекционер:Ландшафтист:Флорист.Инженер-технолог:Кулинар.Модельер:Закройщик:Обувщик.Дизайнер ландшафта:Инженер.Психолог:Следователь:Лаборант.Социолог:Математик:Аналитик.Аудитор:Экономист:Аналитик.Испытатель (техники):Хронометражист.Искусствовед:Критик:Журналист.Зоопсихолог:Орнитолог:Ихтиолог.Биолог:Ботаник:Микробиолог.Лаборант:Дегустатор:Санитарный врач.Эргономик:Контролер:Лаборант.Биолог:Метеоролог:Агроном.Милиционер:Военный:Адвокат.Арбитр:Юрист:Патентовед.Инкассатор:Охранник:Страховой агент.Пожарный:Сапер:Инженер.Постановщик трюков:Каскадер.Егерь:Лесничий:Инспектор рыбнадзора.Эколог:Микробиолог:Миколог.Санитарный врач:Лаборант:Микробиолог.Сторож:Инспектор.Охрана ресурсов:Инженер по ТБ.Таможенник:Прокурор:Табельщик.Корректор:Системный программист.Ревизор:Налоговый полицейский.Техник-контролер:Обходчик ЖД.Выпускающий редактор:Консультант.Консультант:Эксперт по экстерьеру.Селекционер:Агроном:Лаборант.Лаборант-дегустатор:Санитарный врач.Оценщик:Контролер ОТК:Приемщик.Радиолог:Почвовед:Эксперт.";
        String[] starr = string.split("\\.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_KIND
                        + ", " + COLUMN_SPHERE + ", " + COLUMN_ENTITY + ") VALUES (" + i + ", " + k + ", '" + starr[i * 10 + k] + "');");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Активность 2:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;

    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    int x, y = -1;
    Button bt2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content1);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);

        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                y = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);
        radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                x = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //if (x != -1 && y != -1) {
                    String[] params = new String[]{Integer.toString(1), Integer.toString(2)};
                    userCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT entity FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE +
                            " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_KIND + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SPHERE +
                            "=?", params);
                    textView.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
                //}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

По задумке, в DatabaseHelper у меня создается БД database.db и заполняется таблица matrix.

В Main я получаю по одному значению из каждой из двух радиогрупп, а затем эти значения подставляю в строку выборки SQL-запроса.

Первая проблема состоит в том, что вторая радиогруппа вместо значений от 1 до 10 выдает значения от 11 до 20.

А вторая - CursorIndexOutOfBounds когда я, отметив две радиокнопки, пытаюсь получить результат.

Comment: По второй проблеме: `Cursor.getString(columnIndex)` - индекс начинается с `0` и, соответственно, первую и единственную колонку нужно забирать по индексу `0`.

Comment: Насчёт первой - задайте `RadioButton`'ам `id` в разметке как Вам хочется. По умолчанию система генерирует их уникальными в пределах активности, что бы не было проблем при поиске `findViewById`

Comment: Хм. А иных путей исправить проблему с радио-кнопками нет? Прописывать каждую кнопку довольно времязатратно, да и возможно увеличение их количества. Возможно есть какие-либо иные View-представления? Я знаю только нечто подобное - ListView, но в данной ситуации он не особо подходит. – alexeypm 10 минут назад

Comment: А вот с `ListView` мне кажется проще. Задать ему режим `singleChoice`, надписи для кнопок положить в `<string-array>`, создать `ArrayAdapter`. Обработчик нажатия возвращает позицию в списке, а не `id` кнопки - то что нужно. Для изменения количества или порядка кнопок потребуется всего лишь подправить ресурс `<string-array>`

Comment: Получить позицию в радио-группе всё-же можно таким образом: `x = group.indexOfChild(group.findViewById(checkedId)) + 1;`

Comment: Хм. С одной проблемой - определением индекса, я справился. Но по второй все так же - кричит о выходе за границы массива.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, изначально курсор стоит перед строкой и его надо переместить, а так же проверить, что попытка удалась. Если Вы уверены в том, что результат запроса одна строка, то :   `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {...} else { showError("пусто"); }`

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо большое!